# How to publish oracle apex app in internal network for users?

Tags: authentication, networking, publish, apex, internals

I am a newbie in learning about oracle apex
How to publish oracle apex app in internal network for users?
Is it the same as publishing asp.net web?
Can you help me, please?

I try get Login page address and then configure in DNS server but it failed